# Images in Watermark in Google App Engine (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, watermark, blobstore

How to use ImageService in AppEnginge to add watermark on images. Images are uploaded to blobstore then serve. Simple text watermark will do.

Any reference on this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using [`ImagesServiceFactory.makeComposite`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesServiceFactory#makeComposite%28com.google.appengine.api.images.Image,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20com.google.appengine.api.images.Composite.Anchor%29), which allows you to specify X and Y positions and an opacity for an image to composite onto a canvas (the base image). Simply include your watermark image as a resource your app can access using [`ImagesServiceFactory.makeImageFromFilename`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesServiceFactory#makeImageFromFilename%28java.lang.String%29).