# how to add watermark into image in GAE JAVA platform

Tags: google-app-engine

How to add watermark into image in Google App-engine JAVA platform?
Is there any sample java codes?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I tried it looks like some classes are restricted with GAE. (Graphics2D, ImageIO classes).

I also tried on this link below : It could work but it combines 2 images together. what I need is adding dynamic text into image. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553232/images-in-watermark-in-google-app-engine-java

Comment: you can combine image with watermark and original image, so you'll get your watermarked image